# Pandas: Use a series to do list look up

Tags: python, list, pandas, series

I have a series of ints, `s`, and a list of ints, `l`. I would like to construct a new series `t` such that `t[i] == l[s[i]]`. `pandas.Series` has a method called `map` which does this for `dict` objects, meaning something like this would work:

```
t = s.map({i: v for i, v in enumerate(l)})
```

but is there a more direct way?

Comment: IIUC, can't you just `t = s.map(pd.Series(l))`?

Comment: `t = [l[s[i]] for i in range(len(s))]` ?

Comment: @EdChum yes, you can! I guess that's the correct answer?

Comment: @Alexander no relationship between length of `l` and `s`, but `max(s) < len(l)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already have a list of ints then you can just construct a Series from this and pass this as the data param for `map`:

```
t = s.map(pd.Series(l))
```

I don't know if you Series `s` index are random values or not and you really want to perform a lookup, if so then you could pass the values as the index when constructing the Series:

```
In [15]:
s = pd.Series(np.arange(4))
l = [0,4,7,9]
s

Out[15]:
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
dtype: int32

In [16]:    
s.map(pd.Series(index=s.values, data=l))

Out[16]:
0    0
1    4
2    7
3    9
dtype: int64
```